# Lower power version of ULN2803?

Tags: led, power, integrated-circuit, shift-register

I want to drive around 80 LEDs from an Arduino with 10 8-bit shift registers.  (Some will be RGB LEDs; I count those as 3.)  I know of the TPIC6B595 high power shift register but it's expensive: 1.75 USD from DigiKey and Mouser.  I would prefer to do this cheaper.

I can get 74HC595 low power shift registers for 50 cents and ULN2803A Darlington arrays for 65 cents from Futurlec.  That is a total of 1.15, so I'd save $6 on the whole setup.

But the ULN2803A is way overpowered for LED's - each pin can sink 500 mA! Is there anything similar to the ULN2803A, but lower power and even cheaper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ULN2003A are usually quite a bit cheaper, but only 7 channels.

BTW, they're not really good for 500mA, if you read the datasheet critically, you'll see it's more like 50 or 60mA per channel with all channels active, assuming a reasonable temperature range.

From the [Toshiba datasheet](http://www.semicon.toshiba.co.jp/info/docget.jsp?pid=ULN2803APG&lang=en&type=datasheet), the lower graph is for Ta = 85°C

[image]

Comment: Cool, this is very helpful.  All LEDs on for 100% duty cycle is definitely possible in this project, so it looks like the ULN2803A is not so overpowered after all.

Comment: Why is there such a large price difference between the ULN2803 and ULN2003? It seems like the '2803 wouldn't be that much harder to manufacture.

Comment: @CalebReister You're right. It has little to do with manufacturing cost, everything to do with demand and competition.

Answer (score 3):

While the ULN2803 *can* sink 500 mA per output (with a total limit of 2.5 Amp), it will only sink what you let it - if the LEDs have resistors to limit the current to 20 mA, that's all the ULN2803 will see.

You could use individual transistors instead, but I think the convenience of a single package makes a  ULN2803 a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can get TI 16 channel constant-current [LED drivers](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv1098=254&FV=fff40027,fff802d4,fffc0128,15c001b,154c0001&k=led%20driver&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) from Digi-key for cheap and you'll only need 5.